Existing webservice throwing error after Azure Webjob deployment
I have created a pipeline to deploy a Azure Webjob featuring a console application.
Its getting deployed to the wwwroot where there is already another webservice is deployed.
After webjob deployment the existing webservice is throwing below error on invoke :
IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '39dertg3-5152-47d1-b8a3-45342a7a9aa4'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'fd9969df-4e05-4622-b4f1-14c021ae1973' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.

Moreover, How can I deploy azure job to another directory (for instance `D:/home/site/jobs`)?
Pipeline as mentioned below.
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
   - main

stages:
  - stage: "Build"
    jobs:
      - job: "Build"
        variables:
          buildConfiguration: 'Release'
          buildPlatform : 'AnyCPU'
          solution : '**/*.sln'
          project : '**/*.csproj'
        pool:
            name: Azure pipelines
            vmImage: windows-latest 
        steps:
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          name: "Restore"
          displayName: "Restore"
          enabled: true
          inputs:
            command: 'restore'
            projects: '$(project)'
            feedsToUse: 'select'
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: "Build"
          inputs:
            command: 'build'
            projects: '$(project)'
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: "Publish"
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishWebProjects: false
            projects: '$(project)'
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/AzureBlobCleanUp'
            zipAfterPublish: false
            modifyOutputPath: false
        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          displayName: "Archive"
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/'
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: 'zip'
            archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/AzureBlobCleanUpJob.zip'
            replaceExistingArchive: true
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          displayName: "Build Artifacts"
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            ArtifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'Container'
  - stage: "Dev"
    dependsOn: Build
    #variables:
    #- template: yaml-pipeline/vars-dev.yml

    jobs:
      - job: "DeploymentToDev"
        steps:
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
          displayName: "DownloadArtifact"
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            downloadType: 'single'
            artifactName: 'drop'
            downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
            cleanDestinationFolder: true
        - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
          inputs:
            ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
            azureSubscription: 'SHVN DEV ARM Service Connection'
            appType: 'webApp'
            WebAppName: 'app-core-appsvc'
            packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'


Please share your code, If possible please share your code repo.
